# Series expansion of $\sinh z$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

I have been trying to prove that the series expansion of $\sinh{z}$ around $z=1$ is
$$\sinh{z}=\sinh(1) + (z-1) \cosh(1) + \frac{1}{2} (z-1)^2 \sinh(1) + \frac{1}{6} (z-1)^3 \cosh(1) + O((z-1)^4)$$
I know that $$\sinh{z}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$ and I tried the transformation $z\rightarrow{z-1}$, but it didn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint: $
\sinh z = \sinh ((z - 1) + 1) = \sinh 1\cosh (z - 1) + \cosh 1\sinh (z - 1).
$

Comment: Thank you so much. It works!!

Comment: Are you familiar with the Taylor expansion? Probably worthwhile to be. The derivatives have a nice form, it's easy to read off the coefficients.